# Wordpress widget not showing on all pages - html problem?

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook

A widget in SideBarOther shows up on the main article listing page, but when I select an article (same page layout, the article replaces the listing), the widget isn't there. There are two items in SideBarOther, and only the 2nd one has this problem (see code below). If I remove the first one, it is correctly gone from from both the listing page and article page, and the 2nd one still only shows up on the listing page.  I'm using an unmodified "News Magazine Theme 640" theme.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/[our-page]/[our number]" title="[our name]" 
target="_blank"><img src="../pics/fbook_button.jpg" boder="0" alt="[our name]"></a>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like 
href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/[our name]/[our number]" layout="box_count" 
show_faces="false" width="50"></fb:like>
```

NO, I am not confusing which widget is not appearing - the local directory reference ../pics on the first widget works on all pages.  The Facebook Like button is the one that isn't appearing on all pages.

This is not hosted by Wordpress, rather Wordpress v. 2.92 is installed on our website.

(I tried the official wordpress forum, and got no reply.)

UPDATE
I "viewed page source" in Firefox, and THE CODE IS THERE on the article page, and it's IDENTICAL to the listing page. So why isn't it displayed??? I tried the Opera browser, same results. I added another copy of the first widget, and two of them appear on the listing page, and on the article page - the box automatically adjusted to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>` before the Facebook Share Code solved this problem.  This was discovered after I found that if I disabled the Facebook Share plugin, the like button then worked.